# C++: define macro to take an argument, and expand into multiple arguments of another macro?

Tags: c++, macros, arguments

I need boo to take either two explicit variables/constants, or a single macro invocation which expands to two variables/constants. Currently, this does not compile. Foo, once expanded, doesn't seem to be treated as multiple arguments for boo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int getInt(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;   
}

#define boo(x, y) getInt(x, y)
#define foo(x) x, 1

int main()
{
  std::cout << boo(foo(1));
  std::cout << boo(1, 2);
}
```

Any ideas?

https://godbolt.org/z/79o7Td66x

Comment: The reason it doesn't compile is thsat the expansion of `foo` is treated as a single token e.g. that token is `1,1` after evaluating `foo(1)`, but to pass it to another macro or a function it needs to be a set of tokens (i.e. `1`, `,`, and `1` need to be a set of three tokens).     In any event, why do `foo()` and `boo()` need to be macros at all?  Why not `int boo(int x, int y = 1) {return getInt(x,y);}`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use macros (unless you need to).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int getInt(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;   
}

int boo(int x, int y = 1)  { return getInt(x,y); }
int foo(int x) { return x; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << boo(foo(1));
  std::cout << boo(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm not surprised at the downvote.   People who ask questions like this take it poorly when they're told "don't do what you asked, do this instead".   Even when that, legitimately, is the only correct and valid response.

Comment: Doesn't scale if OP has also `#define foo2(x) x, 2` BTW.

Comment: @Peter a complete answer should perhaps more thoroughly explain why OPs inteded solution doesnt work. On the other hand "any ideas?" is rather vague and I really don't understand what is the actual problem OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number   Possibly, but that can require a pretty detailed discussion of how translation associated with the preprocessor works (text substitution, token handling, etc) works.   As you say, the question is vague.  It also strikes me as an XY problem - the OP seems to have decided they need/want to use the preprocessor (so asked about that) rather than describing a problem (for which using the preprocessor may or [more likely in this case] may not be a viable option).

Comment: Also, note that the OP has not actually responded to my query (below the question).  I think I wrote that comment and you wrote your answer concurrently, but essentially I was querying why an option like you've suggested is unsuitable.